# Scrollspy not working for navbar and showing last navbar item as highlighted(active)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I am facing trouble in implementing scrollspy. I had done as per bootstrap documentation and here's is my code.

```
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-example">
    <div class="wrapper spHeight">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-background">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg menulist"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-example" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
                            <li class="centered active"><a class="menuname" href="#home">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#aboutme">ABOUT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#technical">SKILLS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#education">EDUCATION</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="centered"><a class="menuname" href="#blogs">BLOGS</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="home">
            <div class="banner" id="banner" style="width: 100%; height: 684px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 nopadding" style="height:100%">
                    <!--background slide show start-->
                    <img src="images/wallpaper.jpg" alt="batman" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <!--background slide show end-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="aboutme" id="aboutme">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 centered">
                    <img src="images/kunal.jpg" alt="Kunal Chokshi" class="img-circle topmar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="technical" id="technical">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </section>
        </section>
        <section class="experience" id="experience">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="education" id="education">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="contact" id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">                    
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar-example' })
</script>
```

and here is my output:

[image]

and i still don't get why contact is highlighting, as i have given **active** class to home.

Comment: Have you tried adding height to your sections? It seems to be working fine. [http://jsfiddle.net/0q399Lha/](http://jsfiddle.net/0q399Lha/)

Comment: I am sorry @BarielR. I tried as per u said, but its not working. nor i can see that effect in jsfiddle. More over that contact narbar is showing me active. Could you be more specific please. Thanks anyway.